# accumulate an array of key-value pairs into a single object

Tags: json, object, jq

How can I use `jq` to transform this:

```
[
  {
    "k": "a",
    "v": 123
  },
  {
    "k": "b",
    "v": 456
  }
]
```

into this:

```
{
  "a": 123,
  "b": 456
}
```

Comment: You know, this website is about learning. You should provide samples on what you've tried before so we can assist you any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, since your objects are similar to how entries are structured, you could map them as those key/value pairs and convert to an object that way.

```
map({key: .k, value: .v}) | from_entries
```

Answer (score 4):

Reconstruct each object, and `add` them all to get a big, single one.

```
map({(.k): .v}) | add
```

If your input is a large dataset, `reduce` might be a better choice in terms of performance.

```
reduce .[] as {$k,$v} ({}; . + {($k): $v})
```

Comment: Personally I would just assign the property directly rather than adding a single property object. I'd imagine it would be a lot more efficient since you don't have an object to inspect to do the merge.